# Django Queryset Attribute Error in prefetch related

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have a model Option like this:

```
Option:
    a = OneToOneField(A)
    options = ManyToManyField('self', related_name='parent_options')
```

And then i have another model B:

```
B:
    name
    options = ManyToManyField(Option)
```

I am trying ssomething like this:

```
B.options.through.objects.all().prefetch_related('parent_options')
```

But it is not working. I am getting the following error.

```
 AttributeError: Cannot find 'parent_options' on B_options object, 'parent_options' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: why do you use `through` in the queryset?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it. Will post my solution in some time.

Comment: Hey @Simar do you mind posting your solution?